# Facebook app center - Requirements

Tags: facebook, requirements, facebook-app-center

Thanks for taking time to read this.

I would like to have a Facebook App Center page for my application (Android / iOS).
However I have no real need of facebook login in my game.
Can I have a facebook app center page without having a facebook login button ?

I read the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/guidelines/ .
It say: A mobile app built for iOS or Android that uses Facebook Login for iOS or Facebook Login for Android.

But some friends told me (without official reference) that implementing facebook events is enought. (doc here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-events/ )

Is it somehow true ?

Thx a lot for giving me feedback,

Damien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those reading the answer here, app center does require facebook login in the app, I got the official answer from facebook a few days ago.

Thx